# When to mock database access

Tags: database, unit-testing, testing, mocking, integration-testing

What I've done many times when testing database calls is setup a database, open a transaction and rollback it at the end. I've even used an in-memory sqlite db that I create and destroy around each test. And this works and is relatively quick.

*My question is*: Should I mock the database calls, should I use the technique above or should I use both - one for unit test, one for integration tests (which, to me at least, seems double work).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is that if you use your technique of setting up a database, opening transactions and rolling back, your unit tests will rely on database service, connections, transactions, network and such. If you mock this out, there is no dependency to other pieces of code in your application and there are no external factors influencing your unit-test results.

The goal of a unit test is to test the smallest testable piece of code without involving other application logic. This cannot be achieved when using your technique IMO.

Making your code testable by abstracting your data layer, is a good practice. It will make your code more robust and easier to maintain. If you implement a repository pattern, mocking out your database calls is fairly easy.

Also unit-test and integration tests serve different needs. Unit tests are to prove that a piece of code is technically working, and to catch corner-cases. 
Integration tests verify the interfaces between components against a software design. Unit-tests alone cannot verify the functionality of a piece of software.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

All I have to add to @Stephane's answer is: it depends on how you fit unit testing into your own personal development practices. If you've got end-to-end integration tests involving a real database which you create and tidy up as needed - provided you've covered all the different paths through your code and the various eventualities which could occur with your users hacking post data, etc. - you're covered from a point of view of your tests telling you if your system is working, which is probably the main reason for having tests.

I would guess though that having each of your tests run through every layer of your system makes test-driven development very difficult. Needing every layer in place and working in order for a test to pass pretty much excludes spending a few minutes writing a test, a few minutes making it pass, and repeating. This means your tests can't [guide you](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com) in terms of how individual components behave and interact; your tests won't force you to make things loosely-coupled, for example. Also, say you add a new feature and something breaks elsewhere; granular tests which run against components in isolation make tracking down what went wrong much easier.

For these reasons I'd say it's worth the "double work" of creating and maintaining both integration and unit tests, with your DAL mocked or stubbed in the latter.